# How to store my inputbox value to another inputbox using localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

I want to do is when i type a value on email textbox the value will be also stored in my emailCopy with the help of localstorage without typing it in the email copy textbox.

My problem is when i type a value on email textbox the value of the email textbox didnt store on email copy textbox. I refreshed the page still emailcopy is empty.

html:

```
email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
email copy: <input type="text" name="emailCopy" id="emailCopy" />
```

script:

```
$('#email, #emailCopy').on("blur keyup change", function () {

    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
});

$('#email, #emailCopy').each(function (ind, val) {

    $(val).val(localStorage.getItem($(val).attr("id")));

});
```

Comment: Your code works, http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/4nwgesLb/

Comment: Do you just want to display the same text entered in email in another textbox as user types, or do you want to keep both after page refresh, or do you just want to show copy after refresh, what is it..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you are running this code in a browser that supports the localStorage API which is part of the HTML5 specification. You can check the support dynamically using plain javascript...

```
function storageSupported() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

or using `Modernizr`

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage)
```

Other than that, you're code should work if you specify the correct key and make sure you bind only one event, rather than binding `blur`, `change` and `keyup` at the same time...

```
$(function(){
    $('input').val(localStorage.getItem($('#email').attr("id")));

    $('#email').keyup(function(){
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
        $('#emailConfirm').val(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id")));
    });
});
```

Here's a [JS Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k7ap8aah/1/)

#### What you should fix

The function below will NOT work as you expect...that's not how you should be using `each`

```
$('#email, #emailCopy').each(function (ind, val) {

    $(val).val(localStorage.getItem($(val).attr("id")));

});
```

Instead use the following inside the ready funcion...

```
$('input').val(localStorage.getItem($('#email').attr("id")));
```

because it will set the value for all `input` element, it will retrieve the local storage item  by its key and set it to all `input` elements' value. Of course, there's nothing stopping you from changing the selector

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, (*Assuming you want the value in both fields to be the same*) the issue is that you are trying to load the value corresponding to the `id` of element from `localStorage`. If the user didn't type anything in either of the textboxes, corresponding value will be empty.

You should update a common value in `localstorage` once the user types which will be displayed in both fields.

```
$('#email').on("blur keyup change", function () {
  $('#emailCopy').val($(this).val()); // If you want to display on the go
  localStorage.setItem("email", $(this).val());
});
$('#emailCopy').on("blur keyup change", function () {
  $('#email').val($(this).val()); // If you want to display on the go
  localStorage.setItem("email", $(this).val());
});
$('#email, #emailCopy').val(localStorage.getItem("email"));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4nwgesLb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

$("#email").blur(function(){
  localStorage.setItem("email", $(this).val());
});
$('#emailCopy').val(localStorage.getItem("email"));
```